# Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:Verbose to get full output

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am a beginner at coding and I am using the language java in the program bluej.
The purpose of this code is to convert decimal to binary. The method seems to compile well, but the driver has the error "Some messages have been simplified; recompile with  -Xdiags:Verbose to get full output"

```
/**
 * A driver for the Converter class
 * 
 * @author Aaron Nonymous
 * @version 1.0 
 */
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String decimal1 = "100";



    System.out.print("The binary number " + decimal1);
    System.out.print(" converts to the binary number ");
    System.out.println(converter1.convertDecimalToBinary (decimal1));





    }   
}
```

The method below is the one that contains the code in order to convert decimal to binary.

```
/**
 * Will convert an decimal to a binary number
 * 
 * @param binary  a non-negative binary number with no decimals
 *                expressed as a int
 * @return       The binary equivalent of the decimal number
 *               expressed as a String
 */             

public String convertDecimalToBinary (int decimal)
{   
    int placeValue = 2;
    String binary = "";

    /*
     * gets the last binary digit, multiplies it by the place value,
     * and adds that to the total decimal value
     */
    while (placeValue < decimal)
    {
        placeValue = placeValue * 2;          
    }

    while (placeValue < 1)
    {
        binary += decimal / placeValue;

        decimal = decimal % placeValue;

        placeValue = placeValue / 2;

    }                    

    return binary;
}
```

I cannot test if it works because the driver wont compile. 
I did the decimal to binary on paper to see if the conversion works, and it works. Other than that, I need to solve this compilation error.

Comment: There is no evidence here that the driver won't compile. Only a warning message. If there is an error message preventing compilation, you need to provide it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error. It's a warning, telling you about *other* errors or warnings. *Ergo* there *were* other errors or warnings. You shouldn't focus on only one of them.

Your code may have compiled, although even if there are only warnings you should certainly have a good look at them. Good Java code is almost entirely warning-free.

If you want to know more about the warnings, do what the message tells you to.